# What is the date format to convert from string to date

Tags: vb.net

I have below code to get StringToDate as 04/29/2019, but when use CDate function it's giving me #4/29/2019 12:00:00 AM# value. which date format i have to use to get 04/29/2019

```
    Dim StringToDate As Date
    Dim strNewDate As String = "04/29/2019"
    StringToDate = CDate(strNewDate)
```

Comment: You can display the date with the .ToString method however you like, ie, `Console.WriteLine(StringToDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: See also [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact), so you can specify the *exact* Format and Culture.

Comment: A [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7) doesn't have a format. It's just a number. When you display it to the user, you must convert it to a string and you can specify what format to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DateTime.TryParse

```
    Dim MyDate As DateTime = Nothing
    Dim strNewDate As String = "04/29/2019"
    DateTime.TryParse(strNewDate, MyDate)
```

Edit (misread your question)-
A DateTime holds value and not String. To get what you asking after parsing the date you would need to convert it back to a string with a format method or use the following:

```
MyDate.ToShortDateString
```

Comment: still the same, i am getting #4/29/2019 12:00:00 AM#

Comment: Sorry, I misread you question! The DateTime Type just holds a value, not a string. To get what you want you would need to convert the date back to string which allows for formatting. IE MyDate.ToShortDateString

Answer (score 0):

The way a date is represented is by what the region settings of your OS have setup.
For example, if you were to open the region settings in Control Panel you would find a format for Short Date which by what you're describing is probably `M/d/yyyy`. Inside the dropdown are other formats you can set and if you were to set it to `MM/dd/yyyy` you would see that your same code would now display `04/29/2019`. **But Don't Do This** as it only affects your machine. Instead, understand that a date is only number, and you can control how it is displayed, the same way Windows just did from my example. A perfect example of this is that you could set a `DateTime` variable in many different ways. Here's a few:

```
Dim dt1 As DateTime = #2019-12-14#
Dim dt2 As DateTime = #1/08/2019#
Dim dt3 As DateTime = #03/03/2019#
Dim dt4 As DateTime = #4/4/2019#
```

The results would be

`12/14/2019 12:00:00 AM`
`1/8/2019 12:00:00 AM`
`3/3/2019 12:00:00 AM`
`4/4/2019 12:00:00 AM`
because that is how windows is set up to show me a `DateTime` as a string.

When you want to display this date to the user in a different format you can simply supply a format to the .ToString() method or use one of the `DateTime` string conversion methods (ie, `.ToShortDateString`, `.ToLongDateString`, etc) You can show the date to the user in a more preferable format.

Taking the last example (dt4) you could use

```
Console.WriteLine(dt4.ToShortDateString) 'and show 4/4/2019
Console.WriteLine(dt4.ToLongDateString) 'and show Thursday, April 4, 2019
Console.WriteLine(dt4.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) 'and show 04/04/2019
```